# $wpdb Update Data in Database

Tags: wordpress

I can read out some data from the database, but it isn't saved when I change it.

Here is the code which retreives the data:

```
$credit_amount = array_sum(
    wp_list_pluck(
        get_wallet_transactions( array(
            'user_id' => $post_author_id,
            'where' => array( array(
                'key' => 'type',
                'value' => 'credit'
            ) ) 
        ) ), 
    'amount' ) 
);

echo $credit_amount;
```

I want to subtract a fixed amount and save it.

```
$credit_amount = $credit_amount-15;
```

Comment: What is the function `get_wallet_transactions` ?

Comment: This is from a Plugin called "Terra Wallet"

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it.
You want to substract 15 credits to the sum of all transaction, and save into into *something* ?
It's not logical.

If you want to substract 15 foreach transactions, here are tips :

- get_wallet_transactions return `woo_wallet_transactions.transaction_id` (primary key)
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/

Comment: I want to Read out as I do the Amount. Then edit it and save it back.

Comment: But you do a sum of amounts of all transactions. This values isn't directly linked to a specific transaction.

Comment: Thank you for open my Eyes here. 
So I have to find another way to add a Transaction to manipulate the outcome. 
Thank you.